# updating programmatically created label navigation bar item

Tags: ios, swift

Hello I am trying to updated a label in the navigation bar  created programmatically and update the score each time the score is changed.I want to update it in the buttonTapped function.I tried navigationItem.title = "Your Score is (score)" but its updating the main title not the one created programmatically .I am new to swift(IOS development in general) please help.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button3: UIButton!
    
    var countries = [String]()
    var score : Int  = 0
    var correctAnswer = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        countries += ["estonia","france","germany","ireland","monaco","italy","nigeria","poland","russia","spain","us","uk"]
        
        button1.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button2.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button3.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        button2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        button3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
        if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
            let secondFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: navigationBar.frame.width / 2, height: navigationBar.frame.height / 2)
            let secondTitle = UILabel(frame: secondFrame)
            secondTitle.text = "Your Score is \(score)"
            navigationBar.addSubview(secondTitle)
        }
        askQuestion()
       
    }
   
    
    
    func askQuestion(action:UIAlertAction! = nil) {
        countries.shuffle()
        correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
        print(correctAnswer)
        button1.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[0]), for: .normal)
        button2.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[1]), for: .normal)
        button3.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[2]), for: .normal)
        title = countries[correctAnswer].uppercased()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var title : String
        if sender.tag == correctAnswer {
            title = "Correct"
            score += 1
            navigationItem.title = "Your Score is \(score)"
            
        }else {
            title = "Wrong"
            score -= 1
            navigationItem.title = "Your Score is \(score)"
            
        }
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "Your Score \(score)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: askQuestion))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a connection to the `secondTitle` you created, and update it instead of `navigationItem.title`.

You can try it to see if this is what you want.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var button1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button3: UIButton!
    private var secondTitle = UILabel()
    
    var countries = [String]()
    var score : Int  = 0
    var correctAnswer = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        countries += ["estonia","france","germany","ireland","monaco","italy","nigeria","poland","russia","spain","us","uk"]
        
        button1.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button2.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button3.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        button2.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        button3.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
        if let navigationBar = navigationController?.navigationBar {
            let secondFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 0, width: navigationBar.frame.width / 2, height: navigationBar.frame.height / 2)
            secondTitle.frame = secondFrame
            secondTitle.text = "Your Score is \(score)"
            navigationBar.addSubview(secondTitle)
        }
        askQuestion()
    }
   
    
    
    func askQuestion(action:UIAlertAction! = nil) {
        countries.shuffle()
        correctAnswer = Int.random(in: 0...2)
        print(correctAnswer)
        button1.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[0]), for: .normal)
        button2.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[1]), for: .normal)
        button3.setImage(UIImage(named: countries[2]), for: .normal)
        title = countries[correctAnswer].uppercased()
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        var title : String
        if sender.tag == correctAnswer {
            title = "Correct"
            score += 1
            secondTitle.text = "Your Score is \(score)"
            
        }else {
            title = "Wrong"
            score -= 1
            secondTitle.text = "Your Score is \(score)"
        }
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "Your Score \(score)", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: askQuestion))
        present(ac, animated: true)
    }
}
```